# UIButton highlighted background image is not showing

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have to create a layout programmatically with several buttons, I create my buttons using the following code:

```
let myButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(100,100,100,100)
myButton.setTitle("Normal", forState: .Normal)
myButton.setTitle("Selected", forState: [.Selected,.Highlighted])
myButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "normal.png"), forState: .Normal)
myButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "selected.png"), forState: [.Selected,.Highlighted])
self.view.addSubview(myButton)
```

The title and image are not changing once pressed.

The same code works if I refer to a UIButton created in the Storyboard.

Is there any other property that I need to set?

Thank you

Comment: Is the button reacting when you tap on it (turns grey)?

Comment: Yes. I can see the change of status

Comment: have you tried to remove .Selected and just using .Highlighted ?

Comment: try to use or | like .Highlighted | .Selected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try splitting the combined `setBackgroundImage` call into two:

```
myButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "selected.png"), forState: [.Highlighted])
myButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "selected.png"), forState: [.Selected])
```

Comment: That works, but I can't realize why the same syntax works with UIButtons created in the Storyboard

Comment: @Ivan what do you mean the same syntax works on storyboard ? I thought storyboard splits up the diffrent states (highlighted and selected).